# Confused on boost::asio::io_context::run() and boost::thread::join()

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-asio, boost-thread

As the boost document stated [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context/run/overload1.html), boost::asio::io_context::run() function blocks until all work has finished and there are no more handlers to be dispatched, or until the io_context has been stopped.

Now I am confused why my code located before one more handler dispatching (t.join()) was not executed until all the handlers completed their works.

I have tried the boost asio tutorial [Timer.5 - Synchronising handlers in multithreaded programs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer5.html)

And I added one line code following the io.run():

```cpp
int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_context io;
    printer p(io);
    boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_context::run, &io));
    io.run();
    std::cout << "between run and join" << std::endl;
    t.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Here are the console outputs:

```
Timer 2: 0
Timer 1: 1
Timer 2: 2
Timer 1: 3
Timer 1: 4
Timer 2: 5
Timer 2: 6
Timer 1: 7
Timer 2: 8
Timer 1: 9
between run and join
Final count is 10
```

I wonder why t.join() was executed before my `std::cout << "between run and join" << std::endl;` code? I expect the output "between run and join" to be before all the 2nd thread's outputs.

I think I must be lost at something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

line with "Final count" is executed in destructor of printer class, that is executed when main reaches return();

run terminates when all timers expires (there is no more work to wait/do)
Once run returns/unblocks  "cout << between run and join" is executed.

Comment: Why "t.join()" was executed before "cout << between run and join"? I also printed out the threads' id and found the 2 threads both were launched before  "cout << between run and join".

Comment: Thread t running 2nd io.run() is done before  t.join() in called because io.run() in main waits io to complete. Why do you think that join is called before cout << "between run and join"?

Comment: Because I see the 2 threads‘ outputs in console are before "between run and join" when I print the threads' ids in print1() and print2() with `std::cout << boost::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;`                             `35c Timer 2: 0 4a4c Timer 1: 1 4a4c Timer 2: 2 35c Timer 1: 3 35c Timer 2: 4 4a4c Timer 1: 5 4a4c Timer 2: 6 35c Timer 1: 7 35c Timer 2: 8 4a4c Timer 1: 9 4a4c 35c btween run and join`

Comment: As I imagined, the 1st thread was launched by `io.run();`. Then `io.run()` blocked and completed all its work. Later, `std::cout << "between run and join" << std::endl; ` was executed and at last, the 2nd thread was launched by t.join() to complete its work (nothing).

Comment: @UFO thread is started and is running when you call `boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_context::run, &io));`. Code `t.join()` just waits till thread completes (if not already) and that happens after io.run() from main returns. For this reason thread is already completed and `join` returns immediately without waiting.

Comment: thank you. It's clear now. boost::thread is started and running while it's created. t.join() or io.run() is just waits for all works getting done.